# Minimal polynomial of eigenvector entries

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $M$ is a matrix with integer entries and that $\lambda$, $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)^{T}$ are an eigenvalue and eigenvector of $M$.

Then $\lambda$ is an algebraic number and we can see this straight away as it is a root of $\chi_M(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, the characteristic polynomial of $M$.

If we add the constraint that $\sum_i v_i = 1$ then each $v_i$ is also an algebraic number. However, for each $i$ is there an easy to describe polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ in terms of the entries of $M$ which $v_i$ is a root of?

Comment: They're all in the extension of the rationals generated by the eigenvalue, if that's any help.

Comment: I did know that, but I really need an explicit polynomial of which v_i is a root.

Comment: Very nice question, +1!

Comment: In fact I would be happy knowing just an upper bound on the height of v_i, that is the maximum of the absolute value of the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of v_i.